# finding a specific part of a variable?

Tags: bash

Ok I know my question seems confusing. So i'll explain it here. So i'm making a mmo with bash script (i am bored don't say do it with java or c++ or something like that please) which i won't really explain other than that when registering I want it so I can have a if statement see if they have anything provocative in their username and then tell them this and then make them make a different username. I'm just trying to make it more appropriate and all. So to make it so I can have the word seen by my if statement I need to have it like this pretty much

```
if [ var == provocative word ]; then
echo "You have a provocative word in your username. Please change"
fi
```

But to do this I'll need it to look if word is in the statement.
I know that in java it is just by doing 'word*' the star making it so if it sees the word it will so whatever the if said even though the thing might of been 'wordghdksjgh'. Thanks in advance for whoever answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check if a variable contains a substring, you can use:

```
if [[ $var == *"foo"* ]]
then
    echo "The variable contains the substring 'foo'"
fi
```

Comment: Is it possible to make this also look in caps in any combination or will i have to input those separately

Comment: shell option `nocasematch`?

Comment: where would I put nocasematch?

Comment: Put shopt -s nocasematch above the test, and shopt -u nocasematch below it somewhere to restore case sensitivity if that's important.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to pattern-matching using

```
if [[ $var = *foo* ]]; then
```

you can also use regular expressions:

```
if [[ $var =~ foo ]]; then  # Successfully match anything with "foo" as a substring
```

The `nocasematch` option applies to regular expression matches as well.

Comment: Nuts, you beat me to `=~`, now I have to throw out my answer with the awful Qubert joke.